# Android Emulator "will run unaccelerated"

Tags: android, xamarin, android-emulator, hyper-v

I have a Mobile App project that I just created in Xamarin - VS 22. I was getting the error in the title. I checked Hyper-V features from "Turn Windows features on or off" tab. I checked and installed "Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors" from SDK Manager. My problem is fixed.
But after a while the error started to appeared again. Why might this error reappear after it was fixed? What should I do?

[When I try to start it from Android Device Manager, there is an error like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VR4pr.jpg)

Processor is AMD.

Comment: I'm editing the title to focus on the "will run unaccelerated" message. If you are still getting deployment errors, please start another question with that.

Comment: Reboot pc. Android Device Manager, select emulator (but don't start yet), rt-click on emulator (when it is NOT running), "Start with Factory Defaults". If still a problem, make a new emulator.

Comment: You just said that you have checked Hyper-V features from "Turn Windows features on or off" tab. So may I know if you are using or have used HYPER-V acceleration? I hope I can help you better then.

Comment: Yes, I'm using HYPER-V acceleration. @HongxinSui-MSFT

Comment: There is still the same error. I will try to make a new emulator. @ToolmakerSteve

Comment: I gave the possible reasons for this error in my Answer, and I hope it will be helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

The prerequisite for using the Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors is to disable Hyper-V acceleration, which means that the two cannot be compatible.
You can refer to [this website](https://github.com/google/android-emulator-hypervisor-driver-for-amd-processors) for details.

For now, I suggest that you only need to check your Hyper-V acceleration after making a new emulator, instead of using the "Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver for AMD Processors".

Comment: You are a hero. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: So now is your problem solved？@卡迪尔·贝斯卡德斯

Comment: Yes. Emulator is really slow. But problem is solved. Sometimes I got black screen in emulator. I dont know it is about this.

Comment: @KadirBeskardes If you agree with my answer, you may mark it, then I will thank you very much.

Comment: I'm not able to mark your comment. There is something "at least 15 reputation" ...

Comment: Ok, looking forward to seeing you next time.